# Kubernetes deployments sometimes work, sometime doesn't

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, devops

I am new to Kubernetes, I am using Google Container Registry to store my private images, I created a secret key named grc-puller-key

When I use the command:
`kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`
I encountered an unexpected behavior. Sometimes pods are successfully spin up, sometimes those don't. When I failed, I describe the logs and see that I have no credential to pull image, but sometimes it does work.

Here is my deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: portfolio
  labels:
    app: portfolio
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: portfolio
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: portfolio
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: portfolio
        image: gcr.io/phuong-devops/portfolio:v1
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 3000 
          protocol: TCP
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: grc-puller-key
```

I am sure that the secret named **grc-puller-key** was created. I am providing a screen shot as below:

https://ibb.co/ZKqLMDK

Comment: can you share erro logs when pull image. ?

Comment: It told that i am not authorized to my container registry.
```Failed to pull image "gcr.io/phuong-devops/portfolio:v1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gcr.io/phuong-devops/portfolio, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'```

Comment: Could you run `kubectl describe pod <your-failing-pod>` ? Isn't the image pulled successfully in next attempt when you wait a little bit longer and not delete your deployment instantly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that one thing from **Kubernetes official documentation** could explain to certain extent such situation. My guess is that when deployment worked it could have used local copy of the required image. Take a look at [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/) section:

In your deployment there isn't any `imagePullPolicy` explicitly defined and **kubernetes** uses the default one:

> The default pull policy is `IfNotPresent` which causes the Kubelet to
>   skip pulling an image if it already exists. If you would like to
>   always force a pull, you can do one of the following:
>
> - set the `imagePullPolicy` of the container to `Always`.
> - omit the `imagePullPolicy` and use :latest as the tag for the image to use.
> - omit the `imagePullPolicy` and the tag for the image to use.
> - enable the `AlwaysPullImages` admission controller.
>
> Note that you should avoid using `:latest` tag, see Best Practices for
>   Configuration for more information.

Most probably when your deployment worked it used local image. You can easily check it in the events of the `Pod` by running:

```
kubectl describe pods your-pod
```

If you don't see the event `pulling image "image-name"` it means this pod has been created without a need of pooling an image so it used the local one. In situation where the image cannot be pulled your `Pod` will enter `CrashLoopBackOff` state and you'll see events describing what exactly happened.

This is actually the only thing which at the moment comes to my mind that could explain such behaviour. You can easily test it by setting any of the above and check if the pattern changes i.e. if the deployment fails constantly if there is some issue with accessing the image registry.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your helps, It turned out when I changed my service account permission to StorageAdmin, everything worked. But I don't know why it leads to such behavior. If I am not authorized to my container registry, It should had been failed all the time. Right? But in fact, It did not.

Comment: Theoretically yes, if you are not authorized the error should be permanent. You can try to compare events in such two pods i.e. the working one and the failing one. It should say something about what's going on under the hood.